# How to require child widget parent to be only particular widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to force some widget to be child only of some particular widget, for example, I have ChildWidget() and I want this widget to be a child of Stack only, otherwise if the direct parent of this widget is not Stack then throw compilation time error, like when the required parameter of the widget is not initialized/passed?

Example of the desired end result:

```flutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WidgetName extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetName({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          child: Placeholder()
        ),
        ChildWidget(), //Everything is okay, child's direct parent is Stack
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          child: ChildWidget(), // Compilation-time error (red underline), because direct ansector is Container, instead of Stack.
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share your ChildWidget

Comment: @pedropimont it actually does not matter, can be anything even ChildWidget in build method can return just standard Container. I am talking about the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the requested feature. However, only run -time error was implemented if someone knows how compilation-time error can be reproduced, please share you solution, will be appreciated.

Although `visitAncestorElements` method is relatively expensive O(N), we are returning false as return value, which means we are checking only 1st element, and the time complexity reduces to O(1).

```
context.visitAncestorElements((element) {
      assert(element.widget.runtimeType.toString().toLowerCase() != directAnsector.toLowerCase(),"Ansector Error");
      return false;
    });
```